# Conditional or Future for Tener

Tags: traducción, condicional, futuro

I had this Spanish translation question:

> If you don't finish your homework you won't have dessert.

This was the answer provided:

> Si no terminas tu tarea no tendrás postre.

I interpret the original sentence to be conditional. Is that not correct? If not, why?

Comment: Conditional comes with `would`.  What `would` you do?  The sentence uses the future tense.

Comment: How is the answer provided not conditional? It's as conditional as the original sentence. The *conditionalness* of the sentence is determined by the use of if/si. Those introduce a condition. A different matter is the conditional conjugation of verbs, which is used in *some* kinds of conditional sentences.

Comment: The example sentences are conditional. The verb of the main clause does not use the conditional form because it is not a counterfactual conditional sentence.

Answer (score 4):

The original English sentence is conditional, and the Spanish sentence provided as an answer is a conditional too.

The Spanish sentence clearly conveys that something will only happen **if** something else happens first. The same way that is almost that you have a conditional in English when you encounter the conjunction `if`, in Spanish you have a conditional when you encounter `si`.

There are different types of conditionals in Spanish (like in English). One of these types depends on the probability of the condition to be met (sure to happen or unlikely to happen). If it is a *real* (likely to happen) condition you use indicative in the "if/si" sentence and future in the subordinate sentence which express what will happen "if/si" the conditions of the first sentence are met.

See the section [III Real vs. unreal conditions](http://users.ipfw.edu/jehle/courses/condic.htm) of the link.

> A real condition is one which may actually come about or at least is viewed as a possibility; thus, in Spanish, the indicative is normally used both in the “if”clause and in the main part of the sentence:
>
> - Si ella viene mañana, iremos al cine.        <sub>If she comes tomorrow [she may actually come], we will go to the movies.</sub>
> - Si nieva mucho, podré esquiar.   <sub>If it snows a lot [it may really snow], I can ski.</sub>